# LD linker script, get current position of LOAD address

Tags: linker, ld, linker-scripts

In linker scripts, I can get the LMA of a section like this

```
 .got : ALIGN(4)
{
    __global_offset_table_flash_start__ = LOADADDR(.got) ;
    ...
} >SRAM_DTC AT>PROGRAM_FLASH
```

When I use

```
 .got : ALIGN(4)
{
    __global_offset_table_flash_start__ = . ;
    ...
} >SRAM_DTC AT>PROGRAM_FLASH
```

or

```
 .got : ALIGN(4)
{
    __global_offset_table_flash_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
    ...
} >SRAM_DTC AT>PROGRAM_FLASH
```

it will give the VIRTUAL memory address. Where I thought the ABSOLUTE would give the LMA, but it doesn't.

Is there also a way to get the current LOAD memory address for `.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only workaround I can figure out is adding a section which only goes to flash.

```
.dummy : 
{
   __global_offset_table_flash_start__ = .;
    
} > PROGRAM_FLASH
```

As far as I can find in the documentation, there is no way to get the "current" load address